# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields repeater , sub-field default value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to create a list of values in my WP ACF repeater sub-field list.
Is there any way to create an array and attach this to a sub-field, so we or anyone can pick a value that comes with the array?

Maybe someone on this forum already encountered this problem and has a solution for this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Put some more detail with code/example.